# c# mapper from list<string> to string

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two classes StudentEntity and StudentDto. StudentDto is of type List and has a property called Columns. Columns property is of string type in StudentEntity. When mapping two classes (StudentDto -> StudentEntity), the Columns property is written to my database as a string with a value like system.generic.collections.list... What should be the appropriate mapping here? Also, if List is 0 length data, I want to get it as NULL. I would appreciate your help.

```
public class StudentEntity
{
    public string Name
    public string Surname
    public string Columns
}

public class StudentDto
{
    public string Name
    public string Surname
    public List<string> Columns
}
```

StudentEntity is associated with EF Core. I want to keep my List value as string json and as I mentioned, if the string size is 0, it should be NULL.

Comment: Where/how (and *why*) are you converting from `List<string>` to `string`?  What do you want that resulting string to look like?  There is no *default* string representation for most objects, other than the name of the class (which is what you're observing).

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You can manually define custom conversion or depending on the database type map to json column.

Comment: "StudentDto is of type List and has a property called Columns", no it's not. It's a class that implements or inherits from nothing and has 3 properties, one of which is a List of string. I think you've got some foundational things to address here first that will likely solve your main question.

Comment: Are you doing a manual mapping or using a library like `AutoMapper`?

Comment: What is `Columns` supposed to contain? Is this an attempt to store "dynamic" content? You aren't dealing with tables and columns here, you're dealing with objects and properties. It's EF's job to map your objects, including possible dynamic objects or dictionaries, to whatever is used for storage like MongoDB, CosmosDB or a relational database

Comment: That means `Columns` (assuming that makes sense, like a list of columns in a skyscraper) should *remain* a List<string>. In EF Core you can configure it to be mapped to JSON or, if you use PostgreSQL, an actual array

Comment: In EF Core 7 you can [map properties to JSON with `ToJson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#json-columns). Perhaps all you need is `modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().OwnsOne(student => author.Columns, ownedBuilder =>{ ownedBuilder.ToJson(); });`

Comment: Could it be that `student => author.Columns` should be `student => student.Columns` ?

Comment: I'm using automapper and my example is a little different. The student class is just an example. The same situation exists in all my classes and I want to establish a general dynamic structure.

Answer (score 2):

If a manual mapping is OK for you, then one way to do it is using JSON (de-)serialization of the `Columns` properties, with a check for the empty/nonempty list scenario.

Here is an example that uses the `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package to do this.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static StudentEntity ToEntity(StudentDto dto)
{
    return new StudentEntity
    {
        Name = dto.Name,
        Surname = dto.Surname,
        Columns = dto.Columns?.Count > 0
            ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto.Columns)
            : null
    };
}

public static StudentDto ToDto(StudentEntity entity)
{
    return new StudentDto
    {
        Name = entity.Name,
        Surname = entity.Surname,
        Columns = string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.Columns)
            ? new List<string>()
            : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(entity.Columns)
    };
}
```

I believe this requires that you use properties instead of fields:

```
public class StudentEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Columns { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public List<string> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

**Working demo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/WEf4RN

Comment: EF Core can map to JSON directly or, if the database supports it, arrays. There's no reason to convert the list to a single string to begin with. Yes, the OP asked for a string mapping but that's most likely their attempt to trick EF

Comment: That is an interesting new feature that I wasn't aware of, thanks.

Comment: Even without that feature, the OP could use a value converter instead of trying to perform database mapping at the entity level

Comment: Also, now that System.Text.Json can provide serialization than using the NewtonSoft Json serializer. But otherwise, this mapper seems to be best simple to the need. Gives the OP the idea to transform as it may require. Either json, comma separated whatever is in the DB.

Comment: im using automapper